# How to Bind a Listview to an observallable collection in a WCF service?

Tags: wpf, wcf, data-binding, observable

I'm Hosting a WCF service in a WPF application. The WCF service has an Observablecollection which I'm trying to bind to the listview in WPF but i keep getting nullreference exception since the list is empty at the time of intialisation. It only gets elements added when the client connects to the Service. My XAML is below

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="341" Margin="42,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="621" x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header=" Time" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Blade Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The Simplified version of the code behind file is below

```
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using SomeNameSpace.WCFService;

namespace SomeNameSpace.WPFHost
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ServiceHost host;
    MyClass SingleTonService;
    MyClass  srvc;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        try
        {             
            SingleTonService = new MyClass();
            host = new ServiceHost(SingleTonService, baseAddresses);             
            host.Open();

            var obj = host.SingletonInstance;

            srvc = (SomeNameSpace.WCFService.MyClass)obj;
            //WPF Section
            *** Getting null reference exception here since the list is emtpy ***
            listView.ItemsSource = srvc.__clientList;
            //Refresh();

        }
        catch(NullReferenceException e)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            host.Abort();
        }
    }
```

The simplified WCFService class is as below

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace SomeNameSpace.WCFService
{
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
                    UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<Client> __clientList = new ObservableCollection<Client>();

    public ObservableCollection<Client> clientList
    { get { return __clientList; } }
    public ICallback Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();

        }
    }

    public bool Connect(Client client)
    {
        if (!clients.ContainsValue(CurrentCallback) && !SearchByName(client.Name))
        {
                __clientList.Add(client);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Client Class

```
[DataContract]
public class Client
{
    private string _name;
    private DateTime _time;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { _time = value; }
    }
}
```

Also, If i bind the observablecollection to the listview after the connect method is called, everything works since the list isn't empty but i can't do this at run time since i tested this using buttonclick event and setting  listview.itemsource 
 in the event after the connect method is called. There will not be any buttons in the final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replaced the line below

```
listView.ItemsSource = srvc.__clientList;
```

with

```
srvc.__clientList.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
```

and in the event handler i used the code below to manually update the list

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                listView.Items.Clear();
                //update listview here
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The disconnect is that an observable collection only sends out events when the collection changes due to adds or removals and not when itself is created.

What you really want to do is bind the listbox to an ordinary list (or keep it an observable collection) on a class (probably a view model) which adheres to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that will notify the XAML that there is new data to show. The binding is best done in XAML.

*How*

So what happens is that when data comes in from the wire, you load up a local (on the stack) list until all the items are gathered. Then when filled assign the local list reference to the List on your view model. At that point the event of Property changed will fire and the data will be shown to the user.

---

I provide an example of MVVM which can be used in the above situation. [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a workaround for my issue. I'm new to WPF and i'm pretty sure there is a better way than what i'm doing here but it works for now :)